# C++ complex term polynomial function fails evaluation

Tags: c++

I am trying to implement a simple [Durand-Kerner](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Durand%E2%80%93Kerner_method) root finding algorithm, but I get errors when trying to compile the code. This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>   // std::stod
#include <complex>

typedef std::complex<double> cplx;

// f(x)
/************************************************/
/// This function doesn't want to be compiled, but
/// it's implemented the same way as the one below
/*************************************************/
cplx f(cplx &coeff, cplx &term, int length)
{
    cplx sum {0., 0.};
    for (int k=0; k<length; ++k)
    {
        sum += coeff[k] * pow(term[k], length - 1 - k);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    cplx *terms {new cplx[argc-1]};
    cplx *initial {new cplx[argc-1]};

    // Convert command-line chars to numbers
    for (int k=1; k<argc; ++k)
        terms[k-1] = std::stod(argv[k]);

    // Initialize the seed roots
    for (int k=0; k<argc-1; ++k)
        initial[k] = pow(cplx(0.4, 0.9), k);

    /// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    /*********************************************************/
    /// This one is the same as f(x) above, but this one works
    /*********************************************************/
    cplx s {0., 0.};
    for (int k=0; k<argc-1; ++k)
        s += terms[k] * pow(initial[k], argc - 2 - k);
    std::cout << s << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

In trying to implement the evaluation of the polynomial, f(x) (the first function), I keep getting this error:  "~/Documents/cpp/Durand-Kerner/main.cpp|13|error: no match for ‘operator[]’ (operand types are ‘cplx {aka std::complex}’ and ‘int’)|".

While the error is clear, I don't understand why, because the function f(x), implemented below the commented "~~~" line, works. If I comment out the f(x) function, I can compile, but not with the function?

I see nothing different between the two, except, maybe, for "length" vs explicit "argc", but "length" will be passed on to the function as "argc-1", so I really don't understand why the error? (I am currently learning C++, if it matters here)

Comment: the error message very clearly states what's different...

Comment: What is your "f(x)"? just an f(x) text?

Comment: It's late now, I'll return in the morning, so I won't be able to see the possible response(s) immediately. But, why the -1?

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I see what it says, I don't understand why one works and the other doesn't.

Comment: @meJustAndrew For example, the terms, as introduced from the command line, are: 1 10 45 105 105 (Bessel).

Comment: Okay, so what is f(x)? in your code, what you comment out is just an f(x) string? then just delete it, it's not an actual c++ function. Or you can define a void f(int x) function which will behave like an f(x) and of course, the data type can differ

Comment: @meJustAndrew I'll edit the question.

Comment: I got it, now, sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears here:

```
sum += coeff[k] * pow(term[k], length - 1 - k);
```

but the actual problem may be in the header of the function where you are sending references (cplx &coeff, cplx &term), but you expect to use them as arrays, or pointers. The solve could be this way:

// f(x)

```
cplx f(cplx *coeff, cplx *term, int length)
{
    cplx sum {0., 0.};
    for (int k=0; k<length; ++k)
    {
        sum += coeff[k] * pow(term[k], length - 1 - k);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

As you can see, I have changed from & sign to *.

Comment: This was the problem, thank you! I am still learning, and I thought that passing a reference would be better than a pointer. Maybe it's time to revisit the pointers&headers chapter.

Comment: well, to send an array, you should only send the first adress from it as a pointer, then you can iterate the rest of it. This is how c++ works. Cheers!